# Custom manage Signing with other's certificates and provision profile

Tags: ios

I have no apple developer account or membership and my supervisor provide me two .p12 files and one .mobileprovision file I don't know how to use them some one helps me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved.....When we have provision profile then we have no need our developer account because we have certificates and provision profile that gives us bridge of developer accounts and devices permission.[Signing without Check automatically manage signing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pnj50.png)

Answer (score 0):

First thing **.p12** file install (On double click to install in the keychain access) and then install **.mobileprovision** provisioning profile (you can see this in iPhone utility configuration).

You required developer account email and password to enter in Xcode preferences.

Steps:- open Xcode -> Click on Xcode -> Prefrencess... -> Account -> then click on + icon to add option for developer account.

then you can use/build/create .ipa using this certificate and provisioning profile.